# Why SFML isn't able to load an image. SFML, C++

Tags: c++, image, graphics, sfml

I've downloaded the SFML library for working with graphics in C++. Everything's ok, but I have an issue: I can't set a sprite using my photo. Image is .png. I really don't know why it doesn't work:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
using namespace sf;
int main()
{
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(800, 800), "Test");
 
    Texture t;
    t.loadFromFile("background.PNG");
    Sprite Background(t);
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.clear(Color::White);
        window.draw(Background);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[The photo of the problem is HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seaVG.png)

So, I simply have empty white window. Help me please to fix this issue.

Comment: does `background.PNG` exist in the current working directory of the executable? Have you tried using an absolute path?

Comment: Oh, yeh, the solution was to write an absolute path of a file. It works! Thank you,  @Alan Birtles :)

Comment: **THE ISSUE IS SOLVED**